# Using keys from a dict to look for the same "keys" in a pandas dataframe, then assign value from dict to dataframe empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key

I have a pandas dataframe with zipcodes.
I also have a dictionary where keys = zipkode and values = regions

**The dictionary**

```
my_regions = {8361: 'Central region', 8381: 'Central region', 8462: 'North region', 8520: 'South region', 8530: 'Central region', 8541: 'South region'}
```

The dataframe has a col name

```
df["zipcode"]= [8462, 8361, 8381,8660,8530,8530]
```

I want to add a new col to the dataframe df with the dict values (region name), when the loop sees that zip code in dataframe is == to zipkode in dict.keys

**I have tried this**

```
my_regions_list = []

for keyname in my_regions:
    for zipcode in df.zipcode:
        if zipcode == my_regions.keys():
            my_regions_list.append(my_regions.values())
            # df["region"] = df.append(my_regions.values())
            df =df.insert(column="region", value = my_r)
```

The list is empty and this is not adding the new row to the existing dataframe...

I also tried to convert it to a dataframe but it makes no sense

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(my_regions.items()),columns = ['ZIPCODE','REGIONNAME'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"zipcode": [8462, 8361, 8381, 8660, 8530, 8530]})

my_regions = {
    8361: "Central region",
    8381: "Central region",
    8462: "North region",
    8520: "South region",
    8530: "Central region",
    8541: "South region",
}


df["name"] = df["zipcode"].map(my_regions)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   zipcode            name
0     8462    North region
1     8361  Central region
2     8381  Central region
3     8660             NaN
4     8530  Central region
5     8530  Central region
```

Comment: Interesting, TIL `.map()` can actually be faster than `.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to keep this up, even though `.map()` is supposedly faster than `.replace()` simply because the results are different, and others may find one or the other more appropriate for their use-case.

Note that the main difference is that `.replace()` will leave the original value intact if no mapping was found, whereas `.map()` produces `NaN` for mappings that don't exist.

```py
df["regions"] = df["zipcode"].replace(my_regions)
```

Demo:

```py
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   zipcode
0     8462
1     8361
2     8381
3     8660
4     8530
5     8530

In [6]: df["regions"] = df["zipcode"].replace(my_regions)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   zipcode         regions
0     8462    North region
1     8361  Central region
2     8381  Central region
3     8660            8660
4     8530  Central region
5     8530  Central region
```